# How to override type definition while using module include in OCaml?

Tags: include, overriding, ocaml

I want to extend a module with `include` directive. Suppose that I have a module A:

```
module A = struct
  type t = |T of int
end;;
```

Then extend it as below:

```
module B = struct
  include A
  type t = |T of int |U of string
end;;
```

However, it's wrong. So how could I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend algebraic types in the way you want.

You *can* extend polymorphic variant types:

```
# type abc = [ `A | `B | `C ];;
type abc = [ `A | `B | `C ]
# type def = [ abc | `D | `E | `F ];;
type def = [ `A | `B | `C | `D | `E | `F ]
```

Maybe this is close to what you want.

However, you still can't have two types with the same name in the same scope. So you would perhaps want to use `t'` as the name of the second type.

Answer (score 1):

Your module `B` is equivalent with

```
module B = struct
  type t = T of int
  type t = T of int | U of string
end;;
```

where two types of the same name declared in one module. This is not possible in OCaml and that's why it failed to compile.

We do not know what you mean by "extend", but if you expect to obtain the same module as `A` with an extra constructor `U` by `include`, for example from

```
module A = struct
  type t = T of int
  let example_of_t = T 0
end
```

to obtain a module equilvalent with

```
module B = struct
  type t = T of int | U of string
  let example_of_t = T 0
end
```

, it just does not work.